# Calling feathers's services in ember js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I have been trying to call feathers's services in ember js, but I have not found any source for my solution! I got lost, so anyone can help me please?

Comment: I think https://github.com/huafu/ember-data-feathers should get you started.

Comment: Looks like joelaleandro put together a simple hook to serialize the services: https://github.com/joelalejandro/feathers-hooks-jsonapify.  This won't take advantage of the socket.io capabilities, but should allow you to use the default JSONAPI adapter that comes with all new Ember projects.